# Javascript How to automatically change word when click without need to refresh browser.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

im quite lost here and not really expert about javascript. I want to display "Thanks for vote" when user click Like or Dislike and the word "Thanks For Vote" is automatically show without need to refresh the page.

Here is my html:

```
{% if poll.privacy == "own" and request.user.get_profile.parliment != poll.location %}
You do not have permission to vote this.
{% else %}
{% if has_vote %}
{% if poll.rating_option == '1to5' %}
<div class="rate">
<div id="poll-rate-{{ poll.pk }}"></div>
</div>
{% else %}

Thanks for your vote.
{% endif %}

{% else %}
{% if poll.rating_option == 'yes_no' %}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rate btn btn-xs btn-success mr5 vote-positive" rel="{% url 'vote_vote' poll.pk 1 %}" alt="{{ poll.pk }}">Yes</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rate btn btn-xs btn-danger vote-negative" rel="{% url 'vote_vote' poll.pk 0 %}" alt="{{ poll.pk }}">No</a>
{% elif poll.rating_option == 'like_dislike' %}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rate btn btn-xs btn-success mr5 vote-positive" rel="{% url 'vote_vote' poll.pk 1 %}" alt="{{ poll.pk }}">Like</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="rate btn btn-xs btn-danger vote-negative" rel="{% url 'vote_vote' poll.pk 0 %}" alt="{{ poll.pk }}">Dislike</a>
{% elif poll.rating_option == '1to5' %}
<div class="rate">
<div id="poll-rate-{{ poll.pk }}"></div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

and here is my javascript:

```
function bindVoteHandler() {
    $('a.vote-positive, a.vote-negative').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('rel');
        var poll_pk = $(this).attr('alt');
        var selected_div = $(this).parent('div');
        selected_div.html('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/loading_small.gif" />');
        $.ajax(link).done(function( data ) {
            var result_div = $('div#vote-result-'+poll_pk);
            result_div.html(data);
            result_div.removeClass('vote-result-grey-out');
            selected_div.html('<small>Thanks for your vote.</small>');
        });
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    bindPostCommentHandler();
    bindLoadCommentHandler();
    bindDeleteCommentHandler();
    bindVoteHandler();
    $('.show-abuse').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#abuseModal .modal-body').load(url);
    });
    //load rating html
    $('#rate_list').load("{% url 'rate_list' request.session.location_parliment_id %}");
});
</script>
```

did anyone know what is the problem why i need to refresh my page after Like/Vote/rate to make it display (Thanks For your vote) ?
please someone know help or share link with me.

Below is the image:

before click Like:
[image]

after click Like:
[image]

then just when i refresh the browser the word will be displayed, it supposed automatically display when click Like.
[image]

Comment: when does the function bindVoteHandler() get called?

Comment: @Alex , Sorry, i didnt post all javascript code. (updated in question) here is this : $(document).ready(function() {
    bindPostCommentHandler();
    bindLoadCommentHandler();
    bindDeleteCommentHandler();
    bindVoteHandler();
    $('.show-abuse').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#abuseModal .modal-body').load(url);
    });

Comment: maybe you should use $.ajax({url: ..., type: ...}).done... and try that one out

Comment: hi @Alex, im not receiving any error, its just i need to refresh the browser to show the "Thanks" for replacing the vote symbol when it voted. can u expand more about that? im not really get it and kinda noob about Js..

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use jQuery for a click function.  When the vote button is pressed this script will show the previously hidden vote confirmation.  If you need to hide the vote buttons I've included that too.  You would obviously need to replace your class names with the appropriate ones.

```
 <style>
    .yourVoteConfirmation {
    display: none;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.yourVoteButton').click(function() {
        $('.yourVoteConfirmation').show('fast');
        // if you need to hide the vote button
        $('.yourVoteButton').css('display', 'none');

    });
    });
    </script>
```